# What are some economics resources I should know of?

Tags: reference-request

There seems to be an overabundance of high quality media thesedays explaining physics, computer science, mathematics giving exposition to ideas in the fields. What are some media giving expositions to serious economcis ideas that I can check out? For eg, is there some analogue of 3blue1brown for economics content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no YouTube channel that is like 3blue1brown for economics to my knowledge. On of our moderators [EconJohn](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtGO-l5UPnrsLXOGG9nMF5w) has a YouTube channel where he explains graduate level economic topics, but I think it is less tailored to laymen like 3blue1brown. There are channels like economics explained, but the quality there is quite bad sometimes their videos contradict established science. There are however some very good books.

For example, DK publishing printed series of books called Big Ideas Simply Explained explaining various sciences to laymen like physics political science etc. They also published the following title in the series:

Big Ideas Simply Explained: The Economics Book: by Niall Kishtainy et al.

The book is excellently written, it targets laymen, it presents economics ideas very objectively. You get everything, it starts with history lesson on how economic thought developed over the years and after that it explains all main branches of economics today and recent advances. It does not explain ideas in such detail as 3blue1brown because it does not go into math behind models and rigorous proofs but it explains ideas conceptually very well.

Comment: Seems like an unexplored market for someone to break into :)

Comment: @SBrian indeed I always wonder why you dont get things like PBS space time or 3brown1blue in econ format, I guess most PhD level economists are too worried about risking mismanaging their time that could be used for publications

Comment: Thanks for the shout out!

Comment: @EconJohn of course you deserve it, I even recommended your channel to students when I was teaching math for economist you have nice explanation of hamiltonian & stuff