# Graduate level economics lecture videos?

Tags: self-study, academic-graduate

I have a background in economics(undergrad + plus some research) I want to try to teach myself graduate level economics. Are there any good lecturers who cover this topic online(youtube or another free source)?

I have tried using multiple university (MIT, Yale ) videos but it seems that most are at an undergrad level.

You know how you can find graduate level physics lectures on youtube? Are there any for econ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/55773/what-are-some-economics-resources-i-should-know-of

Comment: MIT opencourse for example. Any of the commonly used books. What have you researched so far? It is not difficult to find material online and if you have done an undergraduate already, it should also be simple to determine what is a good source.

Comment: I have tried using multiple university (MIT, Yale ) videos but it seems that most are at an undergrad level.

@AkKdemy    You know how you can find graduate level physics lectures on youtube? Are there any for econ?

Comment: Any specific topics?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/14-462-advanced-macroeconomics-ii-spring-2007/ for example? There are loads of videos from the graduate programme in this series, from a wide variety of topics including macro, micro, growth, development, dynamic programming, ...

Comment: @AKdemy when I try to look for it I only get two graduate level courses. Psychology and macro.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker i would atleast like lecture videos for graduate level micro and macro.

Comment: For Microeconomics: https://www.youtube.com/@econ.school/playlists?view=50&sort=dd&shelf_id=3

Answer (score 3):

[Ivan Cavay's lectures](https://sites.northwestern.edu/iac879/teaching/) are quite nice for Econometrics topics going beyond the core. Unfortunately, without problem sets though.

Comment: Are there video lecrures for grad micro and macro?

Comment: How about Sargent for Macro?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHrSUwxSmqg&list=PLLAPgKPWbsiSGvDwJN87YuXEPcf6B0JHd